# RESTful сервисы и ответ со смешанными данными

Tags: url, rest

Есть сервер и есть клиент. Клиенту нужно получить от сервера список супермаркетов и акции которые на данный момент времени проходят в этих супермаркетах.

Раздумываю над выбором одного из вариантов:

1. Сперва получить список всех супермаркетов
   `GET http://myservice.com/shops`
   Затем получить все скидки в этих супермаркетах
   `GET http://myservice.com/shops/discounts`
    
   *(два запроса)*
2. Получить список супермаркетов и скидок за один раз
    e.q. `GET http://myservice.com/shops_and_discounts`
   *(один запрос)*

**Не противоречит ли 2 способ принципам построения RESTful сервисов?

Или возможно лучше использовать 1 вариант?**
Спасибо.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

По идее endpoint `http://myservice.com/shops` уже должен включать в себя всю информацию о магазине, включая все привязанные к каждому магазину скидки, если вам *действительно нужно отобразить все скидки ко всем магазинам* на клиенте.

Однако, обычно большое множество не включается в тело родителя, а получается индивидуально для каждого конкретного объекта. То есть в вашем случае так: `http://myservice.com/shops/{id}/discounts`. Но такой способ не рекомендуется использовать, если нужно получить все скидки от всех магазинов за раз.

Comment: на самом деле так и есть, shop уже включает в себя подмножество discounts. и если сейчас я к примеру обращусь к `/shops` получу магазины с "вложенными" в них скидками. обхват магазинов я ограничиваю параметрами: `/shops?radius=200&lat=12.14&lng=15.67` (в примере показываю все магазины в радиусе 200 метров относительно координат). Вот только вопрос: "хорошо ли это?". Обращаясь по адресу `/shops` думаю вполне логичным было бы ожидать увидеть именно магазины, а не что либо иное. Дня "иного" уже другой эндпоинт. Если бы не вопрос нагрузки на сервер я бы без колебаний выбрал 1 вариант.

Comment: @Alexiuscrow Ну вот тут и нужно найти золотую середину. Теоретически никто нигде не запрещает объекту-родителю включать в себя всех потомков или связанных с ним объектов. Но тут важно оценивать их количество. Очевидно, что логически вы можете, но не станете включать в эндпоинт магазинов все товары, которые продаются в каждом из магазинов, хотя в то же время вполне можно выводить там, скажем, контактные телефоны каждого магазина. Оцените насколько подобный список скидок будет велик и либо используйте просто `/shops`, либо наоборот, создайте эндпоинт `/discounts` с вложением данных о магазинах.

Answer (score 1):

На мой взгляд лучше все данные получить одним запросом, даже если это противоречит REST принципам. Но так же вы можете в этот запрос

> `GET http://myservice.com/shops`

На сервере засунуть всю необходимую информацию, а на клиенте либо показывать дискаунты либо нет.